# Retrofit - The request is executed successfully but response body is null

Tags: java, android-studio

I wanted to get data from news api, but for some unexpected reason, I get null inside response.body() . I can't recognize where is my mistake and where am I'm wrong.

Here is the link of news api [https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines](https://stackoverflow.com)

**Here is example of response :**
`{ "status": "ok", "totalResults": 36, \-"articles": \[ \-{ \-"source": { "id": null, "name": "CBS Sports" }, "author": "", "title": "MLB Opening Day pitching matchup rankings: Max Scherzer vs. Sandy Alcantara, Jacob deGrom vs. Aaron Nola, more - CBS Sports", "description": "All 30 teams are in action to open the 2023 season on Thursday; which ace vs. ace matchup is the best?", "url": "https://www.cbssports.com/mlb/news/mlb-opening-day-pitching-matchup-rankings-max-scherzer-vs-sandy-alcantara-jacob-degrom-vs-aaron-nola-more/", "urlToImage": "https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/r/2023/03/29/fab119bf-0575-489d-b69b-de2eed4d3e3b/thumbnail/1200x675/9b654a9db70910790b82169a8bfa8d8f/scherzer-getty-1.png", "publishedAt": "2023-03-30T05:56:00Z", "content": "The 2023 MLB regular season is upon us. The new schedule means every team will play every other team at least once this year, which equals fewer intradivision games and more interleague play. And of … \[+10344 chars\]" },`

Here is interface where I defined request with parameters.

```
    public interface INewsApiUtilities {

    String BASE_URL="https://newsapi.org/v2/";

     @GET("top-headlines")
     Call<NewsApiResponse> getNews(
        @Query("country") String country,
        @Query("pageSize") int pagesize,
        @Query("apiKey") String apikey

     );
    }
```

Here is class where I initialized retrofit.

```
public class NewsApiUtilities {

    private static Retrofit _retrofit=null;

    public static INewsApiUtilities getApiInterface(){

        if(_retrofit==null){
            _retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(INewsApiUtilities.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

        }
        return _retrofit.create(INewsApiUtilities.class);
    }

}
```

Here is my **Item (for response) class** (with getters and setters which I don't include in this post because I don't want to spam with these).

```
public class NewsItem {

    private String _author;
    private String _title;
    private String _description;
    private String _url;
    private String _urlToImage;
    private String _publishedAt;

    public NewsItem(String _author, String _title, String _description, String _url, String _urlToImage,  String _publishedAt) {
        this._author = _author;
        this._title = _title;
        this._description = _description;
        this._url = _url;
        this._urlToImage = _urlToImage;
        this._publishedAt = _publishedAt;
    }
}
```

**NewsApiResponse**

```
    public class NewsApiResponse {

    private String _status;
    private int _totalResults;
    private ArrayList<NewsItem> _articles;

    public NewsApiResponse(String _status, int _totalResults, ArrayList<NewsItem> _articles) {
        this._status = _status;
        this._totalResults = _totalResults;
        this._articles = _articles;
    }

    public String get_status() {
        return _status;
    }

    public void set_status(String _status) {
        this._status = _status;
    }

    public int get_totalResults() {
        return _totalResults;
    }

    public void set_totalResults(int _totalResults) {
        this._totalResults = _totalResults;
    }

    public ArrayList<NewsItem> get_articles() {
        return _articles;
    }

    public void set_articles(ArrayList<NewsItem> _articles) {
        this._articles = _articles;
    }
}
```

**findNews** method.

```
private void findNews() {
        NewsApiUtilities.getApiInterface().getNews(country,100, apiKey).enqueue(new          Callback<NewsApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsApiResponse> call, Response<NewsApiResponse> response) {
               if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    newsItems.addAll(response.body().get_articles());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Desila se greska!");
            }
        });
 }
```

Ofcourse I get this exception : `\java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method  java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference`
`at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:588)`
`` at com.example.cubatouristguide.ui.news.NewsFragment$1.onResponse(NewsFragment.java:66)` ``

At the end, here is what I get when print out response.toString() (you can find news if you go to this link).
`Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&pageSize=100&apiKey=xxxxxx}`

Comment: You provided your api-key in the post, I've redacted it but you still should delete that key and request a new one so that people can't abuse your account.

Comment: My mistake, Thanks ! Unfortunately there is no option to change api key or to delete account and then generate another one or I can't find it. Do you think is there anything serious that someone can do with news api key ?

Comment: well that depens if all you can do is read data and you haven't paid for it/given your credit card details to them I would assume you're safe.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception message that you have posted, I suspect that you haven't initialised the list `newsItems` because of which it might be `null` and hence the `Null Pointer Exception`.

Can you try adding a debug pointer or log to print the value of the `newsItems` list ?

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately, I already did that, several times in several places (inside this class where is my method find news). The main problem here is why is my response.body () null in case when my response status is 200.